# Square Matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying too hard but still can't solve this, because I can't find any use of (1)...
Let $A, B, C$ be $n \times n$ square matrices with **real** elements and

1. $(A-B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1}$
2. $C = AB^{-1}$.

Prove that

3. $C + C^{-1} = I$

Comment: Please try to write your thoughts.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that $A, B,$ and $C$ are $n\times n$ real matrices and satisfy $1$ and $2$, then prove $3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. It follows from (1) that $(A-B)(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) = I$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it!